# Comparing CSV values

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am not a coder but I've been trying to compare csv raw values and switching the larger value with the first raw and first raw value to the second raw. eg:

```
NumberA, NumberB
10       22
33       44
776.4    779.7
78       77
```

Code:

```
if NumberA[0] < NumberB[0]: 
    NumberA[10] = NumberB[0]
    NumberB[10] = NumberA[0]
```

I am not sure how to write a loop for this. Also, end of this, I want to generate a new CSV file with new changed values. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Please read [ask] and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this, but start with some [examples from the csv library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples) which show how to read a `csv` file and write a new `csv` file.

```
import csv

header = []
rows = []
sortedrows = []

with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    # grab only the first row as the header/column labels
    header = next(reader, None)
    # read the csv data into list `rows`
    rows = list(reader)

for row in rows:
    # convert all values to float for easy comparison
    nums = map(float, row)
    # sort values in descending order 
    sortedrows.append(sorted(nums, reverse=True))

# write sorted data to a new csv file
with open('sorted.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(sortedrows)
```

`sorted.csv` should contain desired results:

```
NumberA,NumberB
22.0,10.0
44.0,33.0
779.7,776.4
78.0,77.0
```

viewed in Excel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `pandas.read_csv()` to read your file ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)) and `pandas.to_csv` to write it out again ([link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)).

You could start learning pandas [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html)

To write your loop I suggest you get familiar with Python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)